# js es6 class register

Tags: javascript, class, dom, ecmascript-6

how i can create dynamic fonction to access to a class ?
In my engine, i create `scene` class.
And for now i access to scene class with a manual register.

```
getClassScene(className){
    switch (className) {
        case 'Scene_Boot'       : return Scene_Boot       ; break;
        case 'Scene_IntroVideo' : return Scene_IntroVideo ; break;
        case 'Scene_Title'      : return Scene_Title      ; break;
        case 'Scene_Map1'       : return Scene_Map1       ; break;
    };
};
```

in this exmaple

> Scene_Boot,Scene_IntroVideo,Scene_Title,Scene_Map1,Scene_Map2

..... are class

How i can make a dynamic string function to get class.

```
 const scene = new (this.getClassScene(classNameString));
```

i need register all new .js files with new class in this register, but i would like know if i can avoid this 
Thanks

Comment: Actually, a `switch` statement or `Map` or something to explicitly list allowed values isn't bad.

Comment: What exactly do you need this for? Where does `classNameString` come from?

Comment: https://github.com/djmisterjon/PIXI.ProStageEditor/blob/fa03c2d47065a868c4f81598b333ddcac686d496/js/core/loaders.js#L90

Comment: Can you not just access `this.DataScenes`? It's unclear where in that code the `Scene_*` variables are declared - are they globals?

Comment: it because scene class are build from my editor, i scan PC folder to found each .js and build the game progression from nwjs , and i need access to the es6 class  register.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "es6 `class` register". But if you scan your folders with an automatic build script anyway, you might as well have it create such a register for your scene classes.